# ¿Cómo configurar gcsfuse para montar un bucket en una vm de google cloud y acceder a los recursos de la mejor manera?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Cuándo se usa gcsfuse para montar un bucket en un vm de google cloud y accedemos a ese recurso, por ejemplo una imagen a través de una url que se configuro para la vm, ejemplo.com/imagen.jpg, ¿se crea trafico interno entre la instancia vm y el bucket montado con gcsfuse?,¿el tiempo de respuesta para la imagen es afectado?, ¿Seria mejor llamarlo desde el bucket por ejemplo https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket/imagen.jpg?, cualquier ayuda es bien recibida.

Answer (score 0):

con el siguiente comando lo debes de poder hacer.

```
sudo mount -t gcsfuse -o implicit_dirs,allow_other,uid=1000,gid=1000 <BUCKET> <PATH>
```

-Verifica que la VM tenga permisos para acceder a cloud storage